# Sort text by value in tag

Tags: sorting, text

it may be a strange question but I really need it. I want to sort such text by value inside id. Actually I need too compare multiple files in such format, but its impossible to do because there are different order. Is it possible to sort it somehow? Or maybe some easy way to convert it to Json? Thank you.

```
<data>
        <id>Some Line</id>
        <text> Text </text>
</data>
<data>
        <id>Another Line</id>
        <text> First Text </text>

</data>
<data>
        <id>First Line</id>
        <text> Another Text </text>
</data>
```

I have tried to sort it, but I  don't know how to do it without converting to json, which I can't do because of the text format. Tools like kaleidoscope has no such functions.

Comment: You don't need to convert to json; there are libraries to read xml as well. For instance in python you can do it with [module `xml` from the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).